# Incompatibility of amsmath, ntheorem, and mathtools with option showonlyrefs

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, ntheorem

In the minimal example

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem} 
\theoremsymbol{$\diamondsuit$}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % endmark appears if this is commented out

\begin{document} 
\begin{defi}
\begin{equation}
A
\end{equation}
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

the endmark at the end of the definition is not shown as expected.

This happens specifically if the environment ends in an equation/align that is affected by the `showonlyrefs` option.

Does anybody have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is referenced in the [`mathtools` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf). It gives two suggestions:

1. Load [`empheq`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) first with the `overload` and `ntheorem` options. Note `mathtools` should always be loaded before `ntheorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[overload,ntheorem]{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem} 
\theoremsymbol{$\diamondsuit$}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}

\begin{document} 
\begin{defi}
\begin{equation}
A 
\end{equation}
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

This does, however, disable various things like `\intertext`.

2. Load `empheq` with just the `ntheorem` option and for the last equation-like environment in the theorem, use `\begin{empheq}{<env>}` instead of `\begin{<env>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ntheorem]{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem} 
\theoremsymbol{$\diamondsuit$}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}

\begin{document} 

\begin{defi}
\begin{empheq}{equation}
A 
\end{empheq}
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```